# how do i change values in .properties file and run a build using this in jenkins

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, integration, devops

i have a basic job that runs a .bat file to do an export of an application from a file server somewhere. it uses a .properties file in standard format to get the login details, server location and application name/version etc

i've made it work from command line and hard coding the values in the .properties file and running it. the export works and saves in the directory i specify.

i moved over to jenkins and it also works using the hardcoded .properties file.

what i want to do now is set the values in the .properties file inside jenkins so it can be updated without having to manually open the .properties file and then run the same .bat file

if someone could provide an example of setting just one value in a .properties file through jenkins, i feel i can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) for Jenkins which allows to inject environment variables into build process, and modify your .bat file to use them instead of reading values from the properties file.

Here are some of the plugin's usecases/features:

> To remove inherited environment variables (PATH, ANT_HOME, ...) at node level (master/slave), available by default for a job run.
>   To inject variables in the first step of the job (before the SCM checkout)
>   To inject variables based on user parameter values
>   To execute an initialization script before a SCM checkout.
>   To execute an initialization script after a SCM checkout
>   To inject variables as a build step obtained from a file filled in by a previous build step
>   To know environment variables used for a build
>   To inject build cause as environment variable for a build
>   To inject environment variables from the evaluation of a Groovy script (powered by Script Security Plugin)
>   To export environment variables as a metadata in your binary repository